# Is there an equivalent to CombinedGeometry in WinRT XAML?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to draw a square with a round hole in it, so that one can see what's behind the rectangle.  I've used the following code to accomplish this in WPF:

```
<Path Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,100"></RectangleGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40"></EllipseGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

The CombinedGeometry class doesn't appear to exist in WinRT-XAML.  Basically I want to create a game board that you drop pieces into from the top, and animate the pieces falling into place behind the board.

Any suggestions for what I should use instead of a CombinedGeometry? ... or suggestions on how to get CombinedGeometry to work in WinRT-XAML?

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0):

It is not really an equivalent, but it can do the Job :

```
  <!-- Creates a composite shape from three geometries. -->
  <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
    <LineGeometry StartPoint="10,10" EndPoint="50,30" />
    <EllipseGeometry Center="40,70" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" />
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="30,55 100 30" />
  </GeometryGroup>
</Path.Data>
```